# Strange thing when Python __setitem__ use multiple key

Tags: python, class, magic-methods

I wan't to test the type of key when use `__setitem__`. But strangely I found some part of code be omitted when use mutiple keys. Here is my test class:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print('Key is {0}, type of key is {1}'.format(key,type(key)))
        self.data[key] = value

f = foo()
```

When use one key it's ok:

```
>>>f[1] = [0,0]
   Key is 1, type of key is <class 'int'>
>>>f[1]
   [0, 0]
```

when use two keys, result is correct, but **why nothing be printed out**

```
>>>f[1][1] = 100

>>>f[1][1]
   100
```

I'm new in python any suggestion will appreciated！

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f[1][1] = 0` is equivalent to

```
f.__getitem__(1).__setitem__(1, 0)
```

It calls **`__getitem__`** on your custom class; and this returns `[0, 0]` or `[3, 4]` or whatever was stored in `f[1]`; in any case this value is a plain Python `list`; then calls the `__setitem__` on this `list`. `list.__setitem__` does not print anything.

Answer (score 5):

`f[1]` calls your `__getitem__` and thus returns a list (`[3,4]` in the case of the freshly initialized object). Then, the second indexing operation `f[1][1]` indexes the object that was returned, the list `[3,4]`, which is not an instance of your class, but simply a list type (as returned by your class).